# Javascript/jquery calculate totals in gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with products details , and a quantity textbox which I added-it's not connected to any DB.
I want it to display for each row the cost (price*quantity) and the total cost for all rows (in label bellow).
I have a few problems with it.
1. It enters a 0 in the quantity textbox, so I need to update the quantity to 1 all the time, and then it calculates.

I know also maybe this can be done better in C# in the rowdataboundevent, suggestions would be appreciated.

please help me undarstand what's wrong.
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("[id*=lblquantity]").val("0");
    });
$("[id*=lblquantity]").live("change", function () {
        if (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
            $(this).val('0');
        } else {
            $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()).toString());
        }
    });
    $("[id*=lblquantity]").live("keyup", function () {
        if (!jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                $("[id*=lblTotal]", row).html(parseFloat($(".price", row).html()) * parseFloat($(this).val()));
            }
        } else {
            $(this).val('');
        }
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $("[id*=lblTotal]").each(function () {
            grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).html());
        });
        $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString());
        $("[id*=hfGrandTotal]").val(grandTotal.toString())
    });
    </script>
```

and here is the code of the gridview in ASP.net.

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGrandTotal" runat="server"  />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        EnableViewState="False" onrowdatabound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-CssClass="price" >

<ItemStyle CssClass="price"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>

                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Summary") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="picPath">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPic" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("picPath") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="lblquantity" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>



        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

thanx

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes

Step1. Make the price a `asp:TemplateField` and add a class to `lblTotal` like this. Also should the Quantity be a textbox in your markup as you have written?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" CssClass="rowprice"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="rowqty" Text="1">
         </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" CssClass="rowtotal"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Step2. Download this [numeric plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) and write this on DOMReady

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rowqty").numeric({
        decimal: false,
        negative: false
    });
});​
```

This is to make the quantity textbox accept only positive integers.

Step3.

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         var priceLabel =  e.Row.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label;
         var quantityTextBox =  e.Row.FindControl("txtQuantity") as TextBox;
         var totalLabel =  e.Row.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label;
         var onKeyUpScript = String.Format(
                                  "javascript:CalculateRowTotal('#{0}', '#{1}', '#{2}');",
                                  quantityTextBox.ClientID,
                                  priceLabel.ClientID,
                                  totalLabel.ClientID);
         quantityTextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", onKeyUpScript);
    }
}
```

Step3. Add an `asp:HiddenField` and an `asp:Label` with `ClientIDMode="Static"`

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfGrandTotal" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
Grand Total: <asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Step4. Add the javascript function on the page

```
function CalculateRowTotal(qty_id, price_id, total_id) {
    var row_quantity = $(qty_id);
    var row_price = $(price_id);
    var row_total = $(total_id);
    var qty = parseInt($.trim($(this).val()), 10);
    if (isNaN(qty) || qty === 0) {
        qty = 1;
        row_quantity.val("1");
    }
    var totalAmount = parseFloat(row_price.html()) * qty;
    row_total.html(totalAmount);
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $(".rowtotal").each(function() {
        grandTotal += parseFloat($(this).html());
    });
    $("#hfGrandTotal").val(grandTotal);
    $("#lblGrandTotal").html(grandTotal);
}​
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow u really know it. I'm just a begginer so this stuff is to much for me. I need something more simle to apply. I dont know what is DOM.

Comment: DOM is document object model. in simple words its your html itself and DOMReady is `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Does this work ? I am having the same problem and after trying this code the keyup never fires.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this in JS since this is client side load + slower.

Fill as you said in your RowDataBound. Yours would be in the GridView2_RowDataBound. 
Just find the control and cast it to the right control and fill the text.

```
((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal")).Text = (price * quantity);
```

You probably have the price and quantity stored in you dataItem. 
I think you also have to convert it to a string since .Text requires a string. 
You could use

```
(price * quantity).ToString()
```

or

```
Convert.ToString(price * quantity);
```

Comment: thanx for answering. How do I do that if I have mulitple rows in the grid view? and also the quantity can be changed by the user, so i need to add a "calcute" button?!
the quantity is textbox inside the grid view, and the price is taken from data table in the session.

Comment: you could add the id or by class. like value1, value2. and with jQuery you access them jQuery(".value1") or jQuery("#value1"). You have to use a loop to bind some function like click or something like that. You could look into jQuery Each function. There are 2 each methods and they are working on different elements. jQuery.each and jQuery(".value1").each

Comment: wow thanx. just to undarstand, i copy the jquery in to my aspx page. do i need to do anything else? how do i replace the var price = 1.25; with the details from the textbox from the gridview?

Comment: You could add it from the code behind with adding the attributes function. Get your control and add it as attribute ((HtmlControl)e.Item.FindControl("price")).Attributes.Add(String.format("price{0}", e.Item.DataItemIndex), "2"); Something like that. This example is from a repeater so in your case you would use e.Row instead of e.Item. Then from the frond-end you can read it with jQuery in the same loop.